# gdd rescue terminate called after throwing an instance of std::bad_alloc

Tags: disk, ddrescue

I'm trying to recover data from a failing hard drive with gddrescue. Gdd rescue runs just fine, finding no shortage of errors, utnil it hits a certain point and exits with the message:

```
copying non-tried blocks... Pass 1 (forwards)terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The terminal command I'm using is

```
sudo ddrescue --no-split /path/to/drive/folder/in/drive /new/drive/disk.iso /logfile.log
```

I also tried using the next option in [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery), but it has a differnt error (apart from saying `--max-tries` is not an option, which I solved by delting said option), which is

```
ddrescue: Can't open input file: Invalid argument
```

In case it matters, the drive is 5TB and has many errors, so many that the log file on the first attempt went up to 8GB before the error